# Can you pass extra parameters in addition to the primary key to the stored proc for Entity Framework 6 deletes?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1 and we have mapped our CUD stored procs to our entities.

Everything works great for creates and updates. However, for deletes, I would like to pass the modified by username to the delete stored proc so that we can log it in the audit tables.

I tried adding these extra parameters to the model builder when I map the stored procs:

```
    private void MapStoredProcNamesWithExtraDeleteParams<T>(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) where T : BaseAuditableObject
    {
        var tableName = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<TableAttribute>().First();

        modelBuilder.Entity<T>()
            .MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
                s.Update(u => u.HasName(string.Format("{0}Update", tableName.Name)))
                 .Delete(d => d.HasName(string.Format("{0}Delete", tableName.Name))
                     .Parameter(x => x.ModifiedBy, "ModifiedBy")
                     .Parameter(x => x.ModifiedBy, "ModifiedDate")
                     .Parameter(x => x.ModifiedBy, "ModifiedByProgramName")
                     )
                 .Insert(i => i.HasName(string.Format("{0}Insert", tableName.Name))));
    }
```

However, that fails because it says there is no ModifiedBy field on the Delete function.

Is there some way to do this or do I have to first update the modified by, save changes, then delete the object, and save changes again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work-around for the issue that allowed me to do what I wanted, albeit with some extra work.

To get around this we added the [ConcurrencyCheck attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.concurrencycheckattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to all the extra properties that we wanted to pass to the delete stored procedure. Next we had to add those properties plus _Original to all the update and delete stored procedures (even though we only used them in the delete ones).

So if your property name was ModifiedBy you would add a parameter to your update and delete stored procs called @ModifiedBy_Original.

Once we did that we could get the data we wanted in the delete stored procs as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The person that last modified the record is not necessarily the person that deletes the record. Adding a concurrency check on ModifiedBy will indeed pass the modifiedby column of the record to the deleted stored proc's parameter named @ModifiedBy_Original but this is not what you need in this case.

I am saying this because we are facing the same issue and are trying to figure out how we can pass the name of the person that deletes a record to the delete stored proc.

Comment: That is correct. We ended up hooking into the SaveChanges method of the DataContext and in there we get a list of items that will be deleted and write a record to the audit log for each. I can elaborate if you are still trying to solve this.